# How can I trigger an off-camera flash with a Polaroid SX 70 or a Yashica-Mat?

Tags: flash, off-camera-flash, old-cameras, polaroid, yashica

I am interested in shooting pictures with off camera flash. I have a Polaroid sx 70 and one medium format Yashica mat 124.
I was wondering if is it feasbile to shoot with off camera flash with one of this two cameras. 
Is there some kind of hack not too dangerous to obtain off camera flash shots with them?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Yashica Mats that came up in a quick Google image search appear to have a [PC sync](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=pc%20sync) port just to the right of the view finder lens.

If yours does, then it's as easy as attaching the flash, setting the shutter speed to X (or slower) and firing away.

---

The Polaroid has a flashbar slot, which can be converted to pc sync like [this](http://www.sx2pc.com/). i wouldn't attempt this unless you know what you're up to.

Failing that, a disposable flashbar flash could trigger an [optical slave](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=optical%20slave&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Aoptical%20slave).

Answer (score 1):

For the Yashica-Mat, there are little adaptors that attach to the cold-shoe on the side of the camera.  They have a hotshoe output and a PC-sync input.  This, plus a short PC-sync cable will allow you to attach a regular flash or wireless flash trigger to the Yashica-Mat.

You might want a backup PC-sync cable because they are notoriously fidgety and easy to break.